# Parts of the commits are getting synced, but the commits made in index.html cannot be synced

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have just begun working on github. While I was modifying the 2048 repository, part of the commits that I have made are getting synced and can be seen on https://campmesh.github.io/2048/, but the changes that I have made in index.html cannot be synced, and thus, make no difference to the webpage. My repository is -https://github.com/campmesh/2048.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this isn't cached in your browser, because I do see the [latest changes of the `index.html`](https://github.com/campmesh/2048/commits/master/index.html), like the [title being changed to Help Ted!](https://github.com/campmesh/2048/commit/e6ad2f603f2fbe96f655ecd0022470415099f17d#diff-eacf331f0ffc35d4b482f1d15a887d3bR5).

As long as the [`gh_pages` branch](https://github.com/campmesh/2048/tree/gh-pages) is updated and pushed, you should see those modifications too in https://campmesh.github.io/2048/.

Comment: Thanks, clearing the cache worked! I tried it on a different browser as well, and everything went smoothly.

PS - Do try out the game at https://campmesh.github.io/2048/.